# How to make accessible fill-out form instructions

Tags: javascript, html, webforms, accessibility, screen-readers

In an online form (html,javascript) I have a tab with several attachments (input type=file).
before that list of attachments I have a section of instructions about attaching files to my form (size, suffix etc.),
within the instructions there is a link to  an online file size reduction guide.
my html looks like:

```
<div class="container">
    <p id="attachmentInstructions">
        <b>Instructions for Attaching Documents</b>
        <ul>
        <li>To attach a file, click on the document field.</li>
        <li>You can attach the following types of documents: gif, jprg, jpg, tiff, tif, bmp, pdf, doc, docx</li>
        <li>The scan must be in black and with a resolution of no more than 300 DPI. Ascertain that the document is readable.</li>
        <li>The total size of attached documents may not be more than 10 MB </li>
        <li><a href="https://forms.gov.il/forms/resources/FileSizeReductionGuide.pdf" target="_blank">click to the online reduction file size guide</a></li>
    </ul>

</p>

<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="doc1">document 1</label>
        <input id="doc1" type="file" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="doc2">document 2</label>
        <input id="doc2" type="file" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="doc3">document 3</label>
        <input id="doc3" type="file" />
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I need to make these instructions accessible for screen-reader users.
I tried to use "aria-describedby" on each of my inputs, but it loses the link (read out by Jaws as plain text).
I need a way to make this section be read out by screen-reader when entering the tab, be readable on demand and the link to be usabale.
Does any one know a way of doing such?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the page in context would help.

Right now it is *accessible* to a screen reader (though I would not nest the `<ul>` in the `<p>` as that is a parsing error and will trigger a WCAG failure, and I would remove the `target` from the link as spawning new windows can be a problem for screen reader users, and I would suggest avoiding a PDF and putting the file size information into an HTML page).

That being said, I think you want to make it more *usable* in general for screen reader users.

Consider this approach:

```
<h2 id="attachmentInstructions">Instructions</h2>
<p>…</p>
<ul>…</ul>

<label for="doc1">document 1</label>
<input id="doc1" type="file" aria-describedby="instLink">
<span id="instLink"><a href="#attachmentInstructions">Detailed instructions above.</a></span>
```

Note I inserted a header (at the highest possible level this page would allow if it had no other content, since we all know there should only be one `<h1>` and it should correspond to the page title).

Now a user can visually see the message next to the field that the instructions are above. The user may also click the link to jump right to the instructions or just scroll up.

A screen reader user will be informed that the instructions are above when on the field (via `aria-describedby`) and may choose to jump up the page (ideally using heading or list navigation if the user has already encountered it and recalls its structure) or activate the link.

I did not put the link in the `<label>` as it is an interactive control nested in another de facto interactive control (since `<label>` is clickable and we don't want users to click expecting one behavior and get another).

This approach satisfies a few different interaction and discovery modes for both visual and screen reader users (including sighted screen reader users, or about 1/3 of screen reader users).

As always, context mattes, audience matters, and goals matter. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: TLDR: use `aria-describedby`. (*Good point is here that the `aria-describedby` does not target the instructions which would have been too repetitive and awfully long to announce, but a short sentence saying that the instructions are above.*)

Comment: do I need to mark the instructions section as improtant text?, if so, what the right way?

Comment: No, but I also am not sure I understand what you mean by "important text". Their placement under a heading and by being linked from the fields gives them the prominence they need. The user decides if it is important (returning users may not, as they already know this).